# Why is it Illegal to create a Pointer to a Pointer that points to a const in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

This is the source of the common "discarded const qualifier at assignment" error. However, I don't understand why it is illegal to do so?

Consider this code,

```
int sum_array(const int *a, int n){
   int sum, *i;
   sum = 0;
   for(i = a; i<a+n; i++)
       sum += *i;
   return sum;
}
```

Obviously I can do the same operation using `i = 0` and comparing `a + i < a+n`; however, it doesn't make sense to me why simply copying the address of a variable into another variable is illegal?

Typically the const variable indicates that the value of a variable cannot be changed. E.g. const int x = 7, here we declare that the value of x should not be changed from 7.

However, with const pointers, creating the "potential" to change the variable is also illegal. I.e. i =  a does not change the value of what a points to, what would truly be "illegal" would be *i = 0, however, i = a is still illegal because it gives us the potential to change a.

I know you can just answer me with "because the language was created that way", I'm just wondering if there's anything I'm missing here.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to use the pointer to non-const data to modify data that is constant (not modifiable).  Using `const int *i;` prevents you writing (by accident) `sum += (*i = 3);` or something equally implausible that modifies the value that `i` is pointing at.

Comment: In this particular case, the local pointer only adds clutter. Correctly written code is `int sum_array(const int *a, int n){
   int sum = 0;
   for(size_t i = 0; i<n; i++)
       sum += a[i];
   return sum;
}`.

Comment: _"Why is it Illegal to create a Pointer to a Const Pointer in C?"_, not to be nit-picky, but isn't this statement a bit misleading? There are no "const pointers" in OP's example. To have a `const pointer`, one would have to write something like, `int sum_array(int * const a, int n)`. Now the pointer `a` is constant.

Comment: You are correct, const before the type protects the pointer and const after the type protects the object being pointed to, my mistake. I updated the title, hopefully that is accurate enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question proposes that, given `const int *a`, `int *i = a;` could be allowed and a subsequent `*i = 0;` would be disallowed (“illegal”).

This is not feasible because it requires the compiler to track information about the source of the data in `i`. At the point where `*i = 0;` appears, the compiler has to know that `i` contains a value resulting from the initialization from `a`.

We could do that in very simple code. But consider that the code may be very complicated, with loops, branches, and function calls. At the point where `*i = 0;` appears, the compiler generally cannot know whether `i` still holds the address from `a` or has been changed to something else. (I expect this is equivalent to the Halting Problem and hence is logically impossible in general).

C uses types to manage this. When `a` is a pointer to `const`, it may only be assigned to a pointer to `const` (unless overridden by explicit cast). So `i` is required to be a pointer to `const`, which enables the compiler to know that the thing it points to should not be modified.

Answer (score 2):

The primary purpose of `const` is to enlist the compiler's help in ensuring that you don't accidentally modify a given object. It uses the type system for this. You can actually circumvent it if you want, by writing an explicit cast; but usually you don't want that, because if you wanted that then that usually means you didn't really want the `const` to begin with.

Comment: Of heaven forbid the `const int*` pointer is assigned to an intervening `void*` pointer and then to `int *`. There are a number of way to defeat the help the compiler is doing its best to provide.

Answer (score 2):

`const` serves two purposes:

1. in the contract of the function call (here `int sum_array(const int *a, int n)`) it means that the argument `a` will not be used by the function to modify the contents pointed by `a`  (`a` is not constant, it is a pointer to things considered constant). Then caller knows that the data will not be modified through call and the compiler must enforce it as it can:
2. inside the function definition, implementor is then protected against accidental modification of contents pointed by `a`. ie. if he tries to write something like `*a = someValue;` then compiler will complain as the contract is violated. But then it also verifies that this contract is respected in anyway. Thus, any derived variable from `a` that may give access to the same data must be considered as `const` or the contract will be violated. Then writing `int *p = a` is a clear violation of that, because `p` is not a pointer to const data, which would let you write `*p = someValue` to modify data.

**Be aware** that `const` doesn't mean that data is const, only that through the pointer it is forbidden to modify the data. Then:

```
const int *a...
int *p = a;
```

is forbidden but

```
int *a...
const int *p = a;
```

is correct because in that case you have a pointer which let you modify data through it and you construct a derived one that restrict access to the same data through the derived pointer. Data is modifiable through `a` but not through `p`. Restricting is never dangerous, opening could.

Of course you can enforce the dangerous derivation by using cast (which lets you remove `const`) but I would not recommend doing so. **Advice**, if you are tempted doing so, please refrain yourself, think again, if after that you really want to do so, let things go hang for a full night and think about it again the day after... Recipe is:

```
const *a...;
int *p = (int *)a; // "seriously refrain" advice
```

Comment: It is C++ example and the question is not about C.